# how to get count from joining two tables in SQL

Tags: sql

Count of manager is incorrect, how to correct this?

```
select BATS.MANAGER,
  count(BATS.MANAGER)
from BATS
join BATS_HIERARCHY
  on BATS.MANAGER_EMAIL = BATS_HIERARCHY.MANAGER_EMAIL
GROUP BY MANAGER
```

Trying to count the number of times a manager appears if the manager's email is in both tables

Comment: could you give us an example please. what does your bats_hierarchy look like, what does your BATS look like and what is the expected result?

Comment: To be clear, are you only trying to count the number of times a manager appears if the manager's email is in both tables?

Comment: There's just not enough information here to help.  What is incorrect with your count?  What are you expecting? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: trying to count the number of times a manager appears if the manager's email is in both tables

Answer (score 0):

IF I had to guess, and  please as comments said : provide more information, I would say that your jointure BATS on BATS_HIERARCHY isn't a 1 to 1.

Maybe some managers have multiple emails or none.
That would explain your 'incorrect' result.
Try a `FULL join` or a `count(distinct bats.manager)` and see if result differ in any way

Answer (score 0):

So the number of times the manager appears in the BATS table if the email exists in both tables:

```
SELECT
  BATS.MANAGER, COUNT(BATS.MANAGER)
FROM
  BATS
WHERE
  EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM BATS_HIERARCHY WHERE BATS.MANAGER_EMAIL = BATS_HIERARCHY.MANAGER_EMAIL)
GROUP BY BATS.MANAGER;
```

This might do it but I haven't tested it.